# printf visible after restoring closed stdout

Tags: c, linux

My goal is to ignore the output to stdout and stderr in a region.
Here is my code:

```
int stdOutCp = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
int stdErrCp = dup(STDERR_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
printf("Works not\n");

dup2(stdOutCp, STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2(stdErrCp, STDERR_FILENO);
close(stdOutCp);
close(stdErrCp);
printf("This should be visible on the console\n");
```

If I skip the dup2 no output is redirected to the screen, but otherwise it is.

Comment: Ehm, you mean you really have to restore the handles?

Comment: I don't really know :) I just want the outputs after this section going to the console again.

Comment: The chances are that `espeak` is not writing to standard output at all.  You'll need to know what it _is_ using, but consider what would happen if you ran your program (without the I/O redirections of standard output etc in it) with its standard output going to a file or `/dev/null`: would the speech still appear?  (Note, too, that de facto the standard input file descriptor is often writable and connected to the terminal; that may get used sometimes if standard input or standard error are not available.  Totally unreliable – but works surprisingly often.)

Comment: If i don't restore the stdout/stderr with dup2 there is no espeak text output, but the speech is.

Comment: You could redirect to `/dev/tty`...

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "ignoring" ?

If you'd like to have no more stdout,stderr you can just close them.

Though, if you don't have these file descriptors anymore (1 and 2) you may encounter -EBADF (Bad File Descriptor). So I'd suggest to open /dev/null after closing stdout/stderr, so that it gets directed to /dev/null, and nowhere else.

Of course, it should be the firsts open/close operations done by your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        fprintf (stdout, "test 0\n");
        fprintf (stderr, "test 1\n");

        close(1);
        close(2);

        /* Can be: assert(open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY) == 1); to control POSIX behavior. */
        open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
        /* Can be: assert(open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY) == 2); to control POSIX behavior. */
        open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);

        fprintf (stdout, "test 2\n");
        fprintf (stderr, "test 3\n");

        return 0;
}
```

And if you just want to close stdout/stderr temporarily and not permanently you need to "save" a copy of stdout/stderr and keep following the same guidelines regarding /dev/null.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    /* Should display something */

    fprintf (stdout, "test 0\n");
    fprintf (stderr, "test 1\n");

    /* Saving filedescriptor 1 to filedescriptor 10 */
    dup2(1,10);
    /* Saving filedescriptor 2 to filedescriptor 20 */
    dup2(2,20);

    /* Should display something */
    fprintf (stdout, "test 2\n");
    fprintf (stderr, "test 3\n");

    close(1);
    close(2);

    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

    /* Can be: assert(open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY) == 1); to control POSIX behavior. */
    open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);
    /* Can be: assert(open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY) == 2); to control POSIX behavior. */
    open("/dev/null", O_WRONLY);

    /* Should not display anything */
    fprintf (stdout, "test 4\n");
    fprintf (stderr, "test 5\n");

    /* Restoring file descriptors */

    dup2(10,1);
    dup2(20,2);

    /* Should display something */
    fprintf (stdout, "test 6\n");
    fprintf (stderr, "test 7\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tried that already and didn't work.
Fflush was the way to go for me.

Comment: if fflush did anything it means that you had a non-empty libc print buffer, no LF character was sent by your two espeak function calls.  Which means setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0); setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0); before calling them would also have done the trick.  More CPU-intensive though.

Comment: setvbuf did the trick. Fflush worked for me because the process terminates and flushes all the other output. After restoring stdout there was no flush until termination.
But the first code you posted doesn't have setvbuf, without it don't work in my case.